# Materialize Icon moves up when mobile page width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the search icon is vertically aligned. But when I make the width of the page smaller (as viewed on a mobile phone), the search icon jumps up:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed ">

        <nav class="orange " role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Beer Portfolio</a>



                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down left">
                    <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav left">
                    <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
                </ul>


                <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

                <ul class="right ">
                    <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>


    </div>
```

The odd part is I can use vertical align and it will fix it but it moves the Icon to the left....

By just adding the valign-wraper to this line:

```
    <div class="nav-wrapper container valign-wrapper"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Beer Portfolio</a>
```

Fixes my issue but moves the icon like this:

[image]

I cant keep the seaerch vertically aligned and to the right....

Comment: Can you post and relevant CSS for the nav?

Comment: @zgood here is the css http://pastebin.com/s2dQ8QAq

Comment: The HTML and CSS you provided seem solid ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91wscgf3/)). How do your `material-icons` get loaded?

Comment: Any idea whats happening with the icon moving

Comment: As I see it in the fiddle... the `<i class="material-icons">search</i>` has a style of `height:64px;` and `line-height:64px;` and the text "search" in it and it is vertically center and not moving on resize. I do not see the actual search icon because there are no styles for `material-icons` in the CSS you linked. Is there an icon css missing or javascript icon loading missing or some sort of icon framework?

Comment: Need this link for the icons:

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this CSS to your stylesheet it should fix your problem:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 601px) {
    nav, nav .nav-wrapper i, nav a.button-collapse, nav a.button-collapse i {
        height: 64px;
        line-height: 64px;
    }
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch4a3x8s/2/) demoing this solution. To see the problem, remove the css in the Fiddle, run it, then resize the frame window.

The problem was that the materialize.css had this style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 601px) {
    nav, nav .nav-wrapper i, nav a.button-collapse, nav a.button-collapse i {
        height: 64px;
        line-height: 64px;
    }
}
```

It just has a style for `min-width : 601px` so when you would go below that pixel range it would lose those styles it needed to stay center.

I am unsure if this is a bug in their framework css, or if you are missing a mobile css file, mixin, import or whatever.